# Why are the solution for the guess function different?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1st equation is $y''-4y'-12y = e^{6t}$
2nd equation is $y''-4y'-12y = 3e^{5t}$
the solution for the first one $Y_p(t)$ is $Ate^{6t}$
the solution for the second one $Y_p(t)$ is $Ae^{5t}$

why do we add t to the first solution?

Answer (score 0):

The characeristic polynomial of the first equation is $\lambda^2-4\lambda-12=0$ with solutions $\lambda=-2,\ \lambda=6$. The second root (its multiplicity is 1) coincides with the coefficient $6$ in $e^{6t}$. In that case we are adding $t$.

Comment: I think you meant that the multiplicity of the second root is $2$, right?

Comment: No, $6$ is a simple root, its multiplicity is $1$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)#Multiplicity_of_a_root_of_a_polynomial

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of something else. Never mind my previous comment.